# Array Allocation

Tags: c++, sdl

I have a class called SpriteCollection where I load the images with SDL. This class has an attribute called:

```
SDL_Surface* sprites[];
```

I think it's right (though I'm not sure about that). In the same class I have a method:

```
void addNewSprite(SDL_Surface* sprite){

    this->sprites[n_sprites+1] = new SDL_Surface;
    this->sprites[n_sprites+1] = IMG_Load("spritepath.jpg");
    this->n_sprites++;
}
```

And another to retrieve the SDL_Surface to draw on screen:

```
SDL_Surface getSprite(int sprite_index){

    return this->sprites[sprite_index];
}
```

And to draw on the screen I'm using:

```
Draw(x_position, y_position, this->sprite->getSprite[0], screen);
```

I'm loading images normally; it's all OK, but the IDE is returning an error about pointers and conversion between `SDL_Surface` and `SDL_Surface *`.

What am I doing wrong?

edit: the error message:

```
E:\cGame.cpp|71|error: cannot convert `SDL_Surface' to `SDL_Surface*' for argument `1' to `int SDL_UpperBlit(SDL_Surface*, SDL_Rect*, SDL_Surface*, SDL_Rect*)'|
```

Comment: Please post the *exact* error message that you're getting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `getSprite` function which has a return type of `SDL_Surface`, you're trying to return an `SDL_Surface*`. Perhaps you meant:

```
SDL_Surface* getSprite(int sprite_index){
  return this->sprites[sprite_index];
}
```

In addition, these lines are very suspect:

```
this->sprites[n_sprites+1] = new SDL_Surface;
this->sprites[n_sprites+1] = IMG_Load("spritepath.jpg");
```

First you're dynamically allocating a new `SDL_Surface` and storing the pointer to it. Then you're getting rid of that pointer by assigning the result of the `IMG_Load` call to it. Now you'll never be able to `delete` the surface because you've lost the pointer to it. You may think about encapsulating your sprite and using the [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) idiom to handle the allocation of the `SDL_Surface`.

On top of all this, you'd probably be better off using a `std::vector` instead of an array.

Answer (score 3):

```
SDL_Surface getSprite(int sprite_index)
```

Should be:

```
SDL_Surface* getSprite(int sprite_index)
```